# How to add Pomelo toolbox control in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

Video url : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzFY45La2LE

How the toolbox can show with the shortcut command like that? My toolbox was empty. Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nePEY.png)

I searched for a long time but couldn't find the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your toolbox has error then empty, close VS, delete all files in this folder: change "Administrator" to your user name
[image]
Click skip if some file cannot be delete. Now restart VS. It will rebuild configurations and your toolbox will be reset.

If your toolbox is all right(you can right click-show all). The video is just create some code snippets for reuse. Double clike the control will reuse these code for convinient.
[image]